# Get data from pointer that row is pointer

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I try to get header and name rows from "Ads" class and I have second class that is categories ,from that i get objectId.Now I want to get data from "Ads" class where objectId is pass to the categories class to Ads class.Image of two class is

[Ads class ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vayu.png) 
[Categories class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGo8k.png)

Now i write the code for get the data is

```
  let toPass:AnyObject=""
  let picquery = PFQuery(className:"Ads")
 picquery.includeKey("cat") 
  picquery.whereKey("cat", equalTo: toPass)
picquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
              (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                 if error == nil {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    if let objects = objects {
                        self.arrCategories = objects.reverse()
                      self.tblview.reloadData()
                    }
                    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")

        }
        }
```

Here topass is variable that contain the objectId from category class and that id is pass to another controller.And that topass is used in where condition
  Here cat is pointer row so when i run above code the error  in console is

> [Error]: pointer field cat needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version:
>   1.10.0)
>   How can i solve this problem.

Comment: The code supplies a string.  The pointer column must be compared with a pointer.

Comment: I am very new in ios.Can u give me a some line of code?